# Conditional with queryset doesn't exist exception in django without using try/except

Tags: python, django, exception, django-queryset

I need to make an "if" condition with a queryset result as follows :

```
group_child = Groups.objects.get(subgroup = kwargs["group_id"])
            if group_child is None:
                group = get_object_or_404(Groups, group = kwargs["group_id"])
                group.logic_delete()
                messages.success(request, "Deleted successfull")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "It has elements asociated")
```

But code never enters the conditional if queryset doesn't exist cause of course, it throws a django exception and also, im not sure if "is None" is valid at all in this scenario.

I know one way to solve it it's using try/except to capture the exception but i wana know if there's another way so i can use the "if" statement as i need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get) raises an exception if the object is not present in the database. You can use a combination of [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists) like this:

```
group_child_qs = Groups.objects.filter(subgroup = kwargs["group_id"])
if group_child_qs.exists():
    group = group_child_qs.first() 
    group.logic_delete()
    messages.success(request, "Deleted successfully")
else:
    messages.error(request, "It has elements associated")
```

EDIT:

As @knbk mentions, here is a more optimized solution

```
group = Groups.objects.filter(subgroup = kwargs["group_id"]).first()
if group:
    group.logic_delete()
    messages.success(request, "Deleted successfully")
else:
    messages.error(request, "It has elements associated")
```

Comment: @Sayse `group = get_object_or_404(Groups, group = kwargs["group_id"])` and `Groups.objects.get(subgroup = kwargs["group_id"])` have the same net effect if the object exists in the database.

Comment: `.exists()` will execute a second query, you only need one. You can just do `group = qs.first(); if group:`.